# Correct interpretation signed vs unsigned

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation

I'm receiving 2 bytes from a communication and then i need to merge these 2 values to obtain a 16 bit value.

Now suppose that I expect to receive the number 200, then the two characters are **a** and **b**

```
char a=0x00;
char b=0xc8;
int  cw = (a << 8) | b ;
printf("cw= %d\n",cw);
```

Doing the merge the variable cw becomes -56 instead of 200

If i change char by unsigned char i got the correct value 200
How can i fix that? i expect to receive both positive and negative numbers and of course the number 200

Comment: First, definitely use `unsigned char` for the bytes you're reading.  If you can assume that the sending and receiving systems use the same representation for negative numbers (which is certainly a safe assumption, as they both almost certainly use two's complement), then the only remaining problem is to sign-extend negative numbers in the case that ints on your machine are bigger than 16 bits.  It will be something like `if(cw & 0x8000) cw |= 0xffff0000;`.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment, i change to unsigned char and my machine interprets int as 32 bit, I change it to short (16 bit) and now works fine

Comment: Wait. You're expecting to be able to handle *all* 8-bit signed numbers (e.g. -128...127) *and* the value 200 ? Since the latter is not in the range of the former, and you'r receiving octets, what is your plan for differentiating -56, and 200 ? It may sound like it, but I'm not repeating your question. I'm asking a different one. If you need to handle receiving a -56 (which by your statement is possible), what does that octet look like compared to receiving a 200, also represented by an octet?

Comment: @WhozCraig: 200 is the result expected from putting 0x00 into the high eight bits of a signed 16-bit integer and 0xc8 into the low eight bits.

Comment: @WhozCraig He's receiving 16 bits, so he should be fine.  -56 is `ffc8`, and 200 is `00c8`.

Comment: @RicardoCasimiro Yes, using `short int` is a good idea.  `int16_t` might be an even better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard essentially provides no way to shift a 1 bit into or out of the sign position (the only defined cases for `<<` are for non-negative values that do not overflow) and no definite way to convert an unsigned value to a negative value (conversions of out-of-range values to signed integer types are implementation-defined).

So we should not use a shift. However, multiplication of negative values is of course defined, so we can use:

```
int8_t  a;
uint8_t b;
// Put code here to receive a and b by some method.
uint16_t cw = a*256 + b;
```

If you must reconstruct the signed integer from unsigned types, then an option is to test the sign bit and apply the two’s complement manually:

```
unsigned char a, b;
// Put code here to receive a and b by some method.
int cw = (a & 0x7f) << 8 | b;  // Assemble the low 15 bits.
if (a & 0x80)
    cw += -128*256;            // If sign bit is set, adjust.
```

You can also copy the bits in:

```
unsigned char a, b;
// Put code here to receive a and b by some method.
int16_t cw;
memcpy(&cw, (uint16_t []) { (uint16_t) a << 8 | b }, sizeof cw);
```

(The above presume your 16-bit integer uses two’s complement.)

Answer (score 2):

> 16 bit value.

Just use proper type.

```
unsigned char a = 0x00;
unsigned char b = 0xc8;
int16_t cw = ((unsigned int)a << 8) | b;
```

Comment: Honest question: if `a` is e.g. 0xFF, won't you risk/cause signed-integer overflow -> leading to undefined behavior? If not on a 32-bit system, what about if word-size is 16 bit?

Comment: When the high bit of `a` is on, so that `(a << 8) | b` is out of the range of `int16_t`, the conversion to `int16_t` is implementation-defined, in spite of the fact that `int16_t` is specified to be two’s complement. Also, if `int` is 16 bits, then `a << 8` overflows, and the behavior is not defined.

Comment: Och, you got me. When `int` is 16-bit, then `a << 8` will write into the sign bit. Let's just cast it.

Comment: thanks for clarifying @EricPostpischil - and Kamil I still think it's problematic. `cw` should be an `uint16_t` or if it MUST be signed, at least be larger than 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The only change you should do is defining the least significant byte unsigned:

```
char a;
unsigned char b;
... // receive a and b from your communication
int cw = (a << 8) | b;
printf("cw = %d\n", cw);
```

The arithmetic/logic expression should work, but it may be non-trivial to explain why it doesn't overflow, because it involves promotion of `char` or `unsigned char` to `int` (which, I guess, is 16-bit on your system).

If you want your code to be portable (i.e. not assume 16-bit `int` or any other property of your specific platform), use integers with defined size, and do explicit casting.

```
int8_t a;
uint8_t b;
... // receive a and b from your communication
int16_t cw = (int16_t)((int16_t)a << 8) | (int16_t)b;
printf("cw = %d\n", (int)cw);
```

But this code is less readable, so I am not sure being more portable has any advantage here.

Comment: Left-shift of negative values is not defined by the C standard, even if the type is `int16_t`.

Comment: `a << 8` and `(int16_t)a << 8` both cause undefined behaviour if `a` is negative